# Put a limit on lower value for resize while maintaining the aspect ratio with the help of kinetic js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kineticjs, image-resizing

I have been stuck on this for quite some time I am trying to allow drag and resize on an image and I found some example on this link:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/

but I also want to maintain the aspect ratio of the image and I want to put a lower bound on size to which picture can be resized ( shrinked ), i.e I don't wan't the picture to be resized beyond a fixed minimum value.I was able to maintain the aspect ratio by doing some changes but I am not able to put a lower bound on resize without altering the aspect ratio beyond the bound limit.Till now i have accomplished this

http://jsbin.com/iyimuy/115

I can update the code which is mentioned in example provided by the link above between these lines:

```
    newHeight = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
    newWidth = image.getWidth() * newHeight / image.getHeight();
```

by these lines:

```
    newHeight = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
    if(newHeight < 50){
        newHeight = 50;
    };

    newWidth = image.getWidth() * newHeight / image.getHeight();
    if(newWidth < 50){
        newWidth = 50;
    };
```

but i am not able to maintain the aspect ratio then.Kindly state your responses.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to compute the original position of the `activeHandle` (ie where would it be if the user wasn't dragging it). This will be important later, if we learn the size is too small and need to move the `activeHandle` back.

Second, you can use a function like the following to determine an appropriate scaling factor to maintain the aspect ratio (read the article on how to [resize and preserve the aspect ratio](http://blog.acipo.com/resize-and-preserve-aspect-ratio-algorithm/) for more info):

```
function findScale(xSize,ySize,xGoal,yGoal){
    var xScale = xGoal / xSize;
    var yScale = yGoal / ySize;

    if( xScale * ySize > yGoal ){
        return yScale;
    }else{
        return xScale;
    }
}
```

Third, once you've resized it, you need to check if the new size is too small. If it is, then you must move the `activeHandle` back to the position we computed in step 1 and then resize everything.

I edited your code in JS Bin - you can see the working example at: http://jsbin.com/iyimuy/119/

Comment: Your code is wonderful ! It helped me a lot, but can you please check up a small issue with resizing. The problem is sometimes when I start dragging the anchors especially topRight, the bottomLeft anchor also starts dragging, instead it should remain at a fixed position. It happens somtimes only so may be you will have to try it several times. Can you please fix this and post a new JSBin example with the updated code. Thanks ! It was great !

Answer (score 0):

Here it is: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/58YPu/1/)

JS:

```
function update(group, activeHandle) {
        var topLeft = group.get(".topLeft")[0],
            topRight = group.get(".topRight")[0],
            bottomRight = group.get(".bottomRight")[0],
            bottomLeft = group.get(".bottomLeft")[0],
            image = group.get(".image")[0],
            activeHandleName = activeHandle.getName(),
            newWidth,
            newHeight,
            minWidth = 32,
            minHeight = 32,
            oldX,
            oldY,
            imageX,
            imageY;

        // Update the positions of handles during drag.
        // This needs to happen so the dimension calculation can use the
        // handle positions to determine the new width/height.
        switch (activeHandleName) {
            case "topLeft":
                oldY = topRight.getY();
                oldX = bottomLeft.getX();
                topRight.setY(activeHandle.getY());
                bottomLeft.setX(activeHandle.getX());
                break;
            case "topRight":
                oldY = topLeft.getY();
                oldX = bottomRight.getX();
                topLeft.setY(activeHandle.getY());
                bottomRight.setX(activeHandle.getX());
                break;
            case "bottomRight":
                oldY = bottomLeft.getY();
                oldX = topRight.getX();
                bottomLeft.setY(activeHandle.getY());
                topRight.setX(activeHandle.getX());
                break;
            case "bottomLeft":
                oldY = bottomRight.getY();
                oldX = topLeft.getX();
                bottomRight.setY(activeHandle.getY());
                topLeft.setX(activeHandle.getX());
                break;
        }



        // Calculate new dimensions. Height is simply the dy of the handles.
        // Width is increased/decreased by a factor of how much the height changed.
        newHeight = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        newWidth = image.getWidth() * newHeight / image.getHeight();

        // It's too small: move the active handle back to the old position
        if( newWidth < minWidth || newHeight < minHeight ){
          activeHandle.setY(oldY);
          activeHandle.setX(oldX);
          switch (activeHandleName) {
            case "topLeft":
                topRight.setY(oldY);
                bottomLeft.setX(oldX);
                break;
            case "topRight":
                topLeft.setY(oldY);
                bottomRight.setX(oldX);
                break;
            case "bottomRight":
                bottomLeft.setY(oldY);
                topRight.setX(oldX);
                break;
            case "bottomLeft":
                bottomRight.setY(oldY);
                topLeft.setX(oldX);
                break;
          }
        }


        newHeight = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        //comment the below line and uncomment the line below tha line to allow free resize of the images because the below line preserves the scale and aspect ratio
        newWidth = image.getWidth() * newHeight / image.getHeight();//for restricted resizing
        //newWidth = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();//for free resizing

        // Move the image to adjust for the new dimensions.
        // The position calculation changes depending on where it is anchored.
        // ie. When dragging on the right, it is anchored to the top left,
        //     when dragging on the left, it is anchored to the top right.
        if(activeHandleName === "topRight" || activeHandleName === "bottomRight") {
            image.setPosition(topLeft.getX(), topLeft.getY());
        } else if(activeHandleName === "topLeft" || activeHandleName === "bottomLeft") {
            image.setPosition(topRight.getX() - newWidth, topRight.getY());
        }

        imageX = image.getX();
        imageY = image.getY();

        // Update handle positions to reflect new image dimensions
        topLeft.setPosition(imageX, imageY);
        topRight.setPosition(imageX + newWidth, imageY);
        bottomRight.setPosition(imageX + newWidth, imageY + newHeight);
        bottomLeft.setPosition(imageX, imageY + newHeight);

        // Set the image's size to the newly calculated dimensions
        if(newWidth && newHeight) {
            image.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);
        }
      }
      function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var stage = group.getStage();
        var layer = group.getLayer();

        var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          stroke: "#666",
          fill: "#ddd",
          strokeWidth: 2,
          radius: 8,
          name: name,
          draggable: true
        });

        anchor.on("dragmove", function() {
          update(group, this);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
          group.setDraggable(false);
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on("dragend", function() {
          group.setDraggable(true);
          layer.draw();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on("mouseover", function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
          this.setStrokeWidth(4);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on("mouseout", function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = "default";
          this.setStrokeWidth(2);
          layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
      }
      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }
      function initStage(images) {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: "container",
          width: 578,
          height: 400
        });
        var darthVaderGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x: 270,
          y: 100,
          draggable: true
        });
        var yodaGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x: 100,
          y: 110,
          draggable: true
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        /*
         * go ahead and add the groups
         * to the layer and the layer to the
         * stage so that the groups have knowledge
         * of its layer and stage
         */
        layer.add(darthVaderGroup);
        layer.add(yodaGroup);
        stage.add(layer);

        // darth vader
        var darthVaderImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: images.darthVader,
          width: 200,
          height: 138,
          name: "image"
        });

        darthVaderGroup.add(darthVaderImg);
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 0, "topLeft");
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 0, "topRight");
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 138, "bottomRight");
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 138, "bottomLeft");

        darthVaderGroup.on("dragstart", function() {
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        // yoda
        var yodaImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: images.yoda,
          width: 93,
          height: 104,
          name: "image"
        });

        yodaGroup.add(yodaImg);
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 0, "topLeft");
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 93, 0, "topRight");
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 93, 104, "bottomRight");
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 104, "bottomLeft");

        yodaGroup.on("dragstart", function() {
          this.moveToTop();
        });

        stage.draw();
      }

      var sources = {
        darthVader: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
        yoda: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
      };
      loadImages(sources, initStage);
```